# Passing formatted date to hsql from Java

Tags: java, sql, date, format, hsqldb

I am using the following code to generate a date to pass it as date parameter in the hsql database date field.

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
  cal.setTime(new Date());  
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
  Date cutOffDate = cal.getTime();
  String dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(cutOffDate);
  queryBuilder.append(" and c.ContactDt >= :cutOffDate ");
```

But c.ContactDt is Date. I need to pass date. If I pass the value cal.getTime(), it shows invalid format. So I need to convert the `dateFormatter` to date.

I am adding too much code to it to convert. So I guess there must be a better way to do it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As hsqldb specifies a date as "DATE yyyy-mm-dd" you should format it this way.
e.g. "DATE 1990-11-11"

Answer (score 0):

[Calendar.getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) returns a date and [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returns a long.  Here is a sample I use to pass a date into an HSQL stored proc. Notice I convert to java.sql.date.  Probably a better way to do it but at least you see one way.

```
static JSONArray getSigsummXtab(Connection cn, int mySiteid, Date myDate ) throws SQLException {
PreparedStatement pstmt = cn.prepareStatement("{ call rpt.getSigsummXtab(?, ?) }");
pstmt.setInt(1, mySiteid);
pstmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime()));
pstmt.execute(); 
pstmt.close();
}
```

Comment: We are not using regular JDBC

Comment: Here are a couple of sample SQL statements.  Notice you have to put DATE or TIMESTAMP in the statement.  select ( TIMESTAMP(1341414550) ) from (values(0))
select * from ms.ssid where cdate >  DATE '2013-02-09';

Comment: As I mentioned, its not regular JDBC SQL. We are using HQL, JPA Query. So no Statement, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used JPA, but it looked like my suggestion might help with the where clause.  I see now what you are doing.